# Rewriting channel transition probability as equations.

Tags: probability, information-theory, coding-theory

I read from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.5141) (Equations 2 & 3) that for a given channel $p_{Y|Z}(y|z)$, we can write $Y$ as a function of $Z$ and another random variable $W$. For example, for additive white Gaussian noise, we have
$$
p_{Y|Z}(y|z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp{\Big(-\frac{(y-z)^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big)},
$$
which we can rewrite as
$$
Y=f(Z,W)=Z+W,
$$
where $W\sim N(0,\sigma)$. Is this true that we can do this for any channel $p_{Y|Z}(y|z)$? Specifically, I saw another channel from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.02689) (Equation 2):
$$
p_{Y|Z}(y=0|z)=(1-p_2)(p_1)^z,
$$
and
$$
p_{Y|Z}(y=1|z)=1-p_{Y|Z}(y=0|z)=1-(1-p_2)(p_1)^z,
$$
where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are fixed constants to be chosen. I was wondering if it is possible to write $Y$ as a function of $Z$ and another random variable $W$ (which we can choose), but wasn't able to come up with one. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: I've linked the papers to the abstracts instead. I don't think a relevant block diagram is useful for the question and have omitted it.

Comment: Yes, it's always possible, since $\ Y=Z+Y-Z\ $, and, in fact, if $\ Y=Z+W\ $, then $\ W\ $ *must be* $\ Y-Z\ $.

Comment: On looking up the cited paper I see that $\ W\ $ and $\ Z\ $ are random *vectors* rather than random *variables* (which I would normally take to be real-valued, unless otherwise specified).  For random quantities $\ Z\ $ and $\ Y\ $ that are not  necessarily real-valued, my preceding comment needs to be qualified by the specification that both $\ Y\ $ and $\ Z\ $ must belong to the same mathematical structure on which addition is a well-defined operation.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if we can write $Y$ in terms of a function (need not be addition) of $Z$ and $W$ in my second transition probability in my question, where the function need not be an addition like you assumed. For example, eq (4) in the first paper showed the case for logistic channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial answer, which I'm not entirely satisfied with.  Nevertheless, I'm confident that in almost all practical cases the answer to your question is "yes", with some qualifications.

If $\ Y\ $ and $\ Z\ $ are any random quantities taking values in the sets $\ \mathscr{Y}\ $ and $\ \mathscr{Z}\ $ respectively, and the cardinality of $\ \mathscr{Y}\ $ is no greater than than that of the continuum, then for each $\ z\in\mathscr{Z}\ $ let $\ \phi_z:\mathscr{Y}\rightarrow A\subseteq\mathbb{R}\ $ be an arbitrary bijective function, and
$$
W=\phi_Z(Y)
$$
If $\ y,z\mapsto\phi_z(y)\ $ is measurable with respect to appropriate $\ \sigma$-algebras, then $\ W\ $  will be a random variable, and
$$
Y=\phi_Z^{-1}(W)\ .
$$
At this level of generality, some qualifications are:

- There are obviously many (typically an infinite number) of possible families $\ \phi_z\ $ of  bijective functions to choose from, and the vast majority of these (or perhaps even *all* of them in some cases) won't give anything very useful.
- While I believe it will nearly always be possible to choose $\ \phi_z\ $ so that the measurability criteria are satisfied, there may be pathological examples where this isn't possible.

In your second example, $\ y\ $ is $\ 0\ $ or $\ 1\ $ and $\ z\ $ is a real number (in equation  $(2)$ of your second cited paper, where it appears as $\ w_m\ $, it's actually a natural number).  The same is true for equation $(4)$ of your first cited paper.  Since $\ y+z\ $ is therefore a well-defined quantity in both cases, you can still take $\ \phi_z(y)=y+z\ $ and have $\ Y=Z+W\ $ , where $\ W=Y-Z\ $.